# scope.$destroy not triggered on page redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a large AngularJS application with many directives, some of these are encapsulated activeX controls.

A problem we're running into is if the user logs out while viewing an activeX control, the activeX control stays on the page, even though we navigate to a completely new .html page.

We always clean up our directive resources in the `scope.$on("$destroy"` event, and I was hoping I could do that here: just ensuring that the `object` tag is removed from the page on destroy.

The problem I find is that no matter which directive I use as a reference, the `$destroy` event is not being called when `$window.location.assign` is used to redirect to a new page.

I also tested with `$window.location.href` and I get the same result, no `$destroy`s being hit.

Is there a way to ensure `scope.$destroy` is triggered on page redirect?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the most likely reason that a scope isn't getting a `$destroy` event would be if that the directive/controller creating this scope is not wrapped inside the `ng-view` (or directive responding to your routes) HTML element. If that's the case, you'll need to do something to manually work-around it. Is it the case for you that this scope is not under the `ngView`?

Comment: Everything we have in our app is under a ui-views. As we use UI-Router.

Comment: These sorts of scope digest problems can sometimes be fixed by wrapping the $destroy in $timeout.

Comment: It's all in the same heirarchy, but a different scope. I'm not sure it's relevant though, because I'm directing to a new html page/module etc entirely, not just a new route within the same module.

Comment: I think you should try to locate which reference to controller's $scope by using chrome devtool profile

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. And once again, every scope is getting destroyed because we're redirecting to an entirely new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$destroy` is not triggered automatically when leaving the app, only when changing pages within the app. You do have a couple options, though.

**Option 1:**

It sounds like you're manually triggering the leave with `$window.location.assign`, so you could write a function that does both for you:

```
function destroyAndAssign(path){
  $rootScope.$destroy(); 
  $timeout(function(){
    $window.location.assign(path);
  });
}
```

And expose that to the places that need it through a service/provider to call.

**Option 2:**

Otherwise, if you want to attempt to force a `$destroy` every time that the app is left, you can try configuring a `window.onbeforeunload` event when building the app:

```
theApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  var oldOnLeaveEvent = window.onbeforeunload;

  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    $rootScope.$destroy();
    if(angular.isFunction(oldOnLeaveEvent)){
      oldOnLeaveEvent.apply(window, arguments);
    }
  };
}]);
```

However, various things won't be possible at `onbeforeunload` time.